# In terms of app performance, what's the difference between using the camera API to build an in-app camera vs sending an Intent to the camera?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-camera

Is it basically the same process done in a different way? Or do they yield different results under certain circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a question of app performance persay, using the intent approach means you use the phones camera interface. When building an in app camera you are responsible for creating the ui/ux.

I suppose a poorly implemented custom camera would have bad performance over using the built in camera interfaces.

Using a custom camera vs an intent should be more about wether or not you want the user to leave the app and come back vs. stay in a customized ux.

Hope this helps